# My intent is to start an activity with a specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to figure out how to start a different activity with a specific fragment. This is not working and it seems to me that the application restarts.

```
Intent i = new Intent(DetailOrderActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
HistoryFragment fragment = new HistoryFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.Container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: HistoryFragment is in DetailOrderActivity or MainActivity? If it's in MainActivity then you have to use it there.

Comment: Yes, historyfragment is in mainactivity. How do I use it there? I'm sorry still a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DetailOrderActivity.Java remove fragment code from Intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(DetailOrderActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("fragment", 2);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

In MainActivity.Java you will write this code

```
 Intent intent=getIntent();
        int idValue= intent.getIntExtra("fragment", 0);
        if (idValue==2){
            HistoryFragment fragment = new HistoryFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.Container, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
```

Comment: I see so what I have to do is send some data to main activity and let main activity handle that data. Thanks a bunch! You're awesome!